# Actualizar celdas de JTable en tiempo real

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Se puede acualizar las celdas de un Jtable mientras está en pantalla? Tipo se abre la ventana que tiene el JTable y se escribe en él y luego con la info que le pusiste antes, llena otras celdas. Eso es posible?

Comment: La respuesta, tal y como está formulada la pregunta, es simplemente **Sí, se puede**. Quizá quieras editarla y desarrollarla más, añadiendo tu código, para que podamos ayudarte a implementarlo

Comment: Debes utilizar el metodo `addTableModelListener` del modelo que le asignaste al JTable

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar de esta forma para hacerlo donde creas un objeto de una tabla y dentro de esto objeto esta la función de edicion de celda donde le envias la fila y columna con un boton para activar la funcionalidad

```
public class TestTabla {

boolean bandera = false;

public void create() {
    JTable tabla = new JTable(2, 2) {

       public boolean isCeldaEditable(int fila, int columna) {
            if (bandera) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JButton boton = new JButton("Disable");
    boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            bandera = true;
        }
    });
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.add(new JScrollPane(tabla));
    f.add(boton);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new TestTable().create();
        }
    });
}
```